# binding recalculated subset to original data frame in one pipe chain

Tags: r, dplyr, filtering, subset

I've spotted an error (+/- convention has been inverted) with some of the values (y) connected to when a variable country == "CANADA". When I filter by the country variable, and then mutate variable y - how do I "re-insert" this filter into the data frame? I would preferably do this in one dplyr pipe-chain, without having to break the data frame apart, delete the erroneous originals, and then bind the new dataframe to the old without the incorrect values.

```
library(dplyr)
#dataframe df

#Filter retains only mutated values
df %>% filter(country == "CANADA") %>% mutate(y= (-1 * y) %>% ...
```

How do I proceed to reintegrate the corrected values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A reproducible example would have helped to understand the problem better but based on my understanding of the problem I guess you can do

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(y = ifelse(country == "CANADA", -y, y))
```

Or just

```
inds <- country == "CANADA"
df$y[inds] <- -df$y[inds]
```